# Why CLI command gives a different result?

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm working on OCR with tesseract.
On the same picture, when I run on console

```
tesseract alala.png o.txt
```

and cat the o.txt I find this result : 0661183238 which is the correct answer
When I run the python script :

```
digits = tool.image_to_string(Image.open('alala.png'),
                              lang=lang,
                              builder=pyocr.tesseract.DigitBuilder())
print digits
```

I have this result : 0662283238 
Can anybody tell me why ? does the CLI use something different than DigitBuilder ?

Comment: It looks like it does. In that case, look for what are the default settings of the CLI and try to re-do it in the python version. [Here](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html) is the manual page.

Comment: Thanks ! Found out it was using builders.TextBuilder(), I replaced it. Everything is fine now

Comment: I was looking through the pyocr code, and realized that it runs tesseract with `subprocess.Popen()`. If you are only interested in tesseract, it could be the case that you should call it directly from your code.